# How to increase the total price using a toggle button in cart drawer with Shopify Liquid and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

So, I'm trying to make a toggle button that increases the total price of my cart in a shopify site that's using the dawn theme. I already implemented the html and css design and included that onto shopify.

Now, I'm struggling to give this functionality with JavaScript and Liquid. Does anybody have any idea on how to do this?

I'll share a screenshot of the cart implmentation I did with html and css so you get a graphic idea of what I'm looking for:

What I need is to increase those 20.000 to 25.000 once I click the toggle gray button.
Any help would be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkYFu.png)

This is the my html code which I included in cart-drawer.liquid:

```
<div class="toggle-upsell-bar__container">
      <div class="upsell__switch-btn">
        <label class="upsell__switch-toggle">
          <input type="checkbox" />
          <span class="toggle-btn__slider toggle-btn__round"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <p class="toggle-upsell__text">Upsell Feature</p>
      <p class="toggle-upsell__text">+$5.000</p>
    </div>
```

This is my CSS code which I included in base.css:

```
.toggle-upsell-bar__container{
  background-color: rgb(210, 156, 19);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin:20px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.toggle-upsell__text{
  color:white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
  .toggle-upsell__text{
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}


/*This code styles the switch button*/

.upsell__switch-toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
  .upsell__switch-toggle{
    width: 35px;
    height: 22px;
  }
}
/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.upsell__switch-toggle input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.toggle-btn__slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.toggle-btn__slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
  .toggle-btn__slider:before{
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
  }
}

input:checked + .toggle-btn__slider {
  background-color: #302469;
}

input:focus + .toggle-btn__slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .toggle-btn__slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
  input:checked + .toggle-btn__slider:before{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(14px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(14px);
  transform: translateX(14px);
  }
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.toggle-btn__slider.toggle-btn__slider {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.toggle-btn__slider.toggle-btn__slider:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

This is my JavaScript code which I included in cart.js and currently only throws a console.log once I click on the toggle button:

```
const toggleButtonUpSell = document.querySelector('.upsell__switch-toggle input');

toggleButtonUpSell.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (toggleButtonUpSell.checked) {

    console.log('Toggle button activated');
  }
});
```

Honestly, I don't know how to procced now, and any help or advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can't put the price increase into liquid code and JS in Shopify. you need to explore more about Shopify it doesn't allow you update cart item or cart price simply.

Comment: You need to use an extra product approach, draft order API or Shopify scripts if you are on Shopify plus plan.

Comment: If it is for a specific product, you can create a different variant with more price and then add that after removing current variant. Or create an upsell product with price $5.000 and add that to cart on toggle via Shopify Ajax Cart API.